# Connecting to SkypeOnlineConnector using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchangewebservices, skype-for-business

I would like to connect to the SkypeOnlineConnector Endpoint through C# and then be able to execute the commands that are downloaded from the endpoint.

Similar to how a connection is made for the Exchange Commands

Example : Exchange Connection

```
            string severName = "ps.outlook.com/PowerShell-LiveID?PSVersion=2.0";
            string userName = "name@domain.com";
            string password = "Password";

            System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
                secureString.AppendChar(c);
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, secureString);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://" + severName), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential)
            {
                AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic,
                SkipCACheck = true,
                SkipCNCheck = true,
                MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 4
            };
```

I have tried this

```
            string PSServerName = "admingb1.online.lync.com/OcsPowershellOAuth";
            string UserName = "name@domain.com";
            string Password = "password";

            System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password)
                secureString.AppendChar(c);
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(UserName, secureString);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://" + PSServerName), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential)
            {
                AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic,
                SkipCACheck = true,
                SkipCNCheck = true,
                MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 4
            };
```

Running the above gives me the following error

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException : Connecting to remote server admingb1.online.lync.com failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. The authentication mechanism requested by the client is not supported by the server or unencrypted traffic is disabled in the service configuration. Verify the unencrypted traffic setting in the service configuration or specify one of the authentication mechanisms supported by the server.  To use Kerberos, specify the computer name as the remote destination. Also verify that the client computer and the destination computer are joined to a domain. To use Basic, specify the computer name as the remote destination, specify Basic authentication and provide user name and password. Possible authentication mechanisms reported by server: For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Is this the right way of doing it or is a completely different approach required?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you experiencing a specific problem when you try this code?

Comment: I am getting authentication errors. I have tried Basic, Negotiate, Default

Comment: you really need to be more specific. Update your question to show the exact errors you're seeing.

Comment: But from what I can read online, it seems the powershell code you'd need to connect to this service is a bit different. Here's one example: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/skype-for-business-users/connect-to-sfb-online-powershell/m-p/301296/highlight/true#M1062 - there are several similar ones around.

Comment: I have connected through PowerShell using something similar. Just not sure how I can replicate in C#. Although I did find a question which does do the job partially

Comment: @ADyson please see updates